# ResultSet not open. Operation 'moveToInsertRow' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

i'm having a trouble with this error, when i clicked the button, it'll take the values of the labels and put it in the table from database

```
void showAll(){
    try{
        rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BORROW_RETURN");
        while(rs1.next())
        {
            String bookpp = rs1.getString("name");
            String emailse = rs1.getString("email");
            String booktee = rs1.getString("book_title");
            String ser_no = rs1.getString("serial_no");
            String borr = rs1.getString("borrowed");
            String ret = rs1.getString("return");
            loginModel3.addRow(new Object[]{bookpp, emailse, booktee, ser_no, borr, ret});
        }}catch(SQLException err){
            System.out.print(err);
    }
}
```

and this is the connection to the connection to the database

```
void DoConnect1( ) {
               try{
                String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Dafuq7";
                String uName ="Dafuq7";
                String uPass ="Dafuq7";
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

                //EXECUTE SOME SQL AND LOAD THE RECORDS INTO THE RESULTSET
                    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM borrow_return";
                rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                   }


    catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

and upon clicking the button the said error occurs,

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   String ema = jLabel20.getText();
    String enm = jLabel21.getText();
    String booknm = bttl.getText();
    String snnnn = sernum.getText();
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dates = dateFormat.format(date_borr.getDate());
    try {

        rs1.moveToInsertRow();
        rs1.updateString( "book_title", booknm );
        rs1.updateString( "serial_no", snnnn );
        rs1.updateString( "name", enm );
        rs1.updateString( "email", ema );
        rs1.updateString( "borrowed", dates );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HAHA");
        loginModel3.addRow(new Object[]{names, booknm, snnnn, enm, ema, dates});

        con.setAutoCommit(false);
System.out.println(con.getAutoCommit());
rs1.insertRow( );
        stmt.close();
        rs1.close();

        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";

        rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        }
    catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049705/resultset-not-open-verify-autocommit-is-off-apache-debry

Comment: im still having an error

Comment: You should set autocommit off as soon as you create the connection. Don't wait until you have already issued your query; it is too late by then because your query was already auto-committed.

Comment: please, can you be specific on where to put that, i don't know what to do right now, i'm searching for days to find a solution. so can you please.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting autoCommit to false after your queries are really committed. You need to set it false once after you open connection or before start executing your queries.

```
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
        //EXECUTE SOME SQL AND LOAD THE RECORDS INTO THE RESULTSET
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM borrow_return";
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codedump.io/share/WK0Jtw7GEH3h/1/why-do-i-get-javasqlsqlexception-resultset-not-open-operation-39next39-not-permitted-java-derby-database

By default, only one `ResultSet` object per `Statement` object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one `ResultSet` object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different `Statement` objects. All execution methods in the `Statement` interface implicitly close a statment's current `ResultSet` object if an open one exists.